# What is the best way to run this loop and check while looping?

Tags: function, powershell, for-loop

I am writing a code to check if Blue Prism process is running and if it is not to start its listener. I want to try twice and if it fails then stop. I have this

```
$time = Get-Date -Format "dddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm K"
$status = Get-Process Automate -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If (-not $?) 
    {
     for ($count = 1; $count -le 2; $count++)
     {
       startListener
       }
    }
Else {
    #exit
    Write-Host "Up"
    }


function startListener {
    $time | Add-Content -Path "C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\BluePrismDown.txt"
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate\Automate.exe" -ArgumentList "/resourcepc", "/public", "/port 9188", "/dbconname PROD"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}
```

But I am not doing it correctly because there is no additional checking to see if the first try was successful. 
I thought about adding another If(-not $?) but I cannot get that to work

```
$time = Get-Date -Format "dddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm K"
$status = Get-Process Automate -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If (-not $?) 
    {
     for ($count = 1; $count -le 2; $count++)
     {
        If (-not $?) 
        {
        startListener
            }
        Else 
        {
            Break
            }
        }
    }
Else {
    #exit
    Write-Host "Up"
    }


function startListener {
    $time | Add-Content -Path "C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\BluePrismDown.txt"
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate\Automate.exe" -ArgumentList "/resourcepc", "/public", "/port 9188", "/dbconname PROD"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
}
```

I know there has got to be a better way to structure this so that I can check if it worked, if not try again and if I tried twice quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Augment your function to return a boolean indicating whether or not the process stops again within the 30 seconds:

```
function Start-BluePrismListener {
    Get-Date -Format "dddd MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm K" | Add-Content -Path "C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\BluePrismDown.txt"
    $process = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Blue Prism Limited\Blue Prism Automate\Automate.exe" -ArgumentList "/resourcepc", "/public", "/port 9188", "/dbconname PROD" -PassThru
    return -not $process.WaitForExit(30000)
}
```

The `Process.WaitForExit(int milliseconds)` method overload will return `true` if the process exits within the timeout, hence the `-not`. Now we can use the output of the function to decide whether to break out of the loop:

```bsh
if( -not (Get-Process Automate -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) ){
    for ($count = 1; $count -le 2; $count++){
        if(Start-BluePrismListener){
            # didn't exit, looks good, let's break out
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me make sure I understand it correctly, I don't even need to use the $? because I can just say `If (-not (get-process)` and that is the same thing?
And then the reason we can say `If (Start-BluePrismListener)` is specifically because you created the $process variable and then used the waitforexit which like you said will return a true value if it exits within the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

here's a less spiffy way to do what you asked. [*grin*]

swap the comment markers on lines 3 & 4 to allow testing with "failed to start" and "started properly".

```
# the next two allow testing for not started OR started
#   comment out the one you _don't_ want to work with
$TargetProcess = 'BetterNotBeThere'
#$TargetProcess = 'notepad'

$ProcessFilePath = 'C:\windows\notepad.exe'
$RetryLimit = 2

function Get-IsProcessRunning {
    [CmdletBinding ()]
    Param
        (
        [Parameter (
            Mandatory,
            Position = 0
            )]
            [string]
            $TargetProcess
        )

    begin {}

    process
        {
        @($False, $True)[[bool](Get-Process -Name $TargetProcess -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)]
        }

    end {}

    } # end >>> function Get-IsProcessRunning

$RetryCount = 0
while (
    -not (Get-IsProcessRunning -TargetProcess $TargetProcess) -and
    $RetryCount -lt $RetryLimit
    )
    {
    'Trying to start the [ {0} ] process ...' -f $TargetProcess

    Start-Process -FilePath $ProcessFilePath
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

    $RetryCount ++
    }

if (Get-IsProcessRunning -TargetProcess $TargetProcess)
    {
    'The [ {0} ] process it running at this time.' -f $TargetProcess
    }
    else
    {
    Write-Warning ('    Unable to start the [ {0} ] process.' -f $TargetProcess)
    }
```

output with the "not there" process ...

```
 Trying to start the [ BetterNotBeThere ] process ...
 Trying to start the [ BetterNotBeThere ] process ...
 WARNING:     Unable to start the [ BetterNotBeThere ] process.
```

output with notepad as the target process ...

```
Trying to start the [ notepad ] process ...
The [ notepad ] process it running at this time.
```

the 1st started two copies of Notepad.exe - i stopped them before running the 2nd. [*grin*]